# Window glitches when maximized with Task Manager

Tags: windows, task-manager

When I go into Task Manager and select Maximize on a window that can't be, (like the run dialog) the window will act like it can be maximized and will probably look weird. This seems to happen on Windows 10, and 8.1. Also it covers the taskbar which is odd. Is there a fix around this and make the option grayed out, etc., or will they fix this eventually?

Here's an example: (Note: the taskbar is only hidden when the maximized window is in focused).

[image: Maximize option in Task Manager]

[image]

Comment: This is not default behavior. Can you post a screenshot showcasing what you see?

Comment: Hmm what do you know... this also applies to Windows 10. Never knew this could be used. Sounds like a serious oversight on Microsoft's part, but maybe it is an administrative thingy... being able to manipulate this to any program out of the box.

Comment: I can reproduce this as well (Windows 10), seems to be a bug or just a "feature".

Comment: I don't think anyone uses Task Manager's Maximize/Minimize window option, that's probably why it's glitchy.